# plpgsql query - how can i combine if , then with update?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following query:

```
create or replace function test_function()
    returns trigger as $body$
begin
    if (tg_table_name = 'mytable' and tg_op='insert') then
        INSERT into another_table(id, name) values(new.id, new.name);
        return new;
    else if (tg_table_name = 'mytable' and tg_op='update') then
        INSERT into another_table(id, name) values(new.id, new.name);
        return new;
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$body$ language plpsql;
```

EDIT:
I need to do a :

```
update table mytable set name = 'test';
```

EDIT2: this didn't work, the value2 was not updated to null;

```
BEGIN   
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND TG_TABLE_NAME='tableA') THEN
    INSERT INTO tableB(
            columnA,
            columnB)
        VALUES(
            new.value1,
            new.value2);
new.value2 := null;
RETURN NEW;
ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND 
TG_TABLE_NAME='tableA') THEN
    INSERT INTO tableB(
            columnA,
            columnB)
        VALUES(
            new.value1,
            new.value2);
new.value2 := null;
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
RETURN null;
END;
```

EDIT:4

```
create trigger add_notif_trigger after insert or update on 
 mytable for each row when (new.name > 100) execute 
 procedure function test_function();
```

I need to do an update on either conditions. I can't figure it out how to do it.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the column values of base table, you don't need another update, you just assign the `NEW.column_name`

```
if
..

NEW.name := 'test';

else if
..

NEW.name := 'test';
```

Comment: I added an edit to explain what i want to do. I already do an insert into on each clause (if and elseif), i want to do an update table ... on each clause

Comment: @gxg : What do you mean by didn't work? did it gave you an error? Have you checked if the table name is in mixed case? (tableA)  Please provide the table definitions(ddls) of underlying tables and also the main trigger code so that I can replicate the issue

Comment: i didn't receive any error but the value i wanted to change didn't change. The trigger activates on insert and update on tableA and i checked, the insert on tableB worked. I don't know how to explain better my issue

Answer (score 0):

IF THEN 
   IF new.value = true THEN 
   END IF;

END IF;

be careful, 
when you use the update(TG_OP ='UPDATE') you have old and new value, during the insert you have only new value